# Calling next() at the end of custom middleware causes error

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, jwt

I am trying to set up viewpages to show the authenticated user's info such as user's name or email on the page when they are logged in.

To do so, I am using the res.locals function to set the user data at the global level for the pages to access.

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const User = require("../models/User")

const checkUser = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.cookies.jwt
    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, "Company_Special_Code", async (err, decodedToken) => {
            if (err) {
                res.locals.user = null // Set it to null if the user does not exist
                next();
            } else {
                let user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id)
                res.locals.user = user
                next();
            }
        })
    } else {
        res.locals.user = null
        next();
    }
}

module.exports = {
    checkUser
}
```

The first code, where I call next() function every time the code reaches an endpoint, allows the pages to access the user info without any errors.

However, if I call the next() function only once at the very bottom of the checkUser() function, it causes error claiming that the user is not defined at the view page level. The code is as follows:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const User = require("../models/User")

const checkUser = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.cookies.jwt
    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, "Company_Special_Code", async (err, decodedToken) => {
            if (err) {
                res.locals.user = null // Set it to null if the user does not exist
            } else {
                let user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id)
                res.locals.user = user
            }
        })
    } else {
        res.locals.user = null
    }
    next();
}

module.exports = {
    checkUser
}
```

If I coded the function correctly, the checkUser() function should get to the next() function at the bottom regardless of the status of jwt token or if there was an error during the token verification process. I would really appreciate your help if you can tell me what I am getting it wrong here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `jwt.verify` is has an asynchronous callback and `next()` at the bottom is being called before that returns. So you either need to put `next()` into that callback, or use `jsonwebtoken` synchronously. Something like this:

```js
const checkUser = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.jwt
  if (token) {
    try {
      const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, "Company_Special_Code")
      // This only runs if the token was decoded successfully
      let user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id)
      res.locals.user = user
    } catch (error) {
      res.locals.user = null // Set it to null if the user does not exist
    }
  } else {
    res.locals.user = null
  }
  next();
}
```

When you use an async callback like that, javascript will continue processing the rest of the script while that callback is running on the side (more or less). So `next()` is being called unaware of the need to wait for the callback or anything it might handle.

Answer (score 0):

Your validation part misses the correct error handling in middleware. If token is invalid, then why should user get access to controller, you can send error from middleware itself. If you are not sending error from middleware and calling next(), then will defeat purpose of your authentication middleware.
Update your code as follows,

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const User = require("../models/User")
// The routes, which does not requires aurthentication
const usecuredRoutes = []
const checkUser = (req, res, next) => {
if(usecuredRoutes.indexOf(req.path) === -1){
    const token = req.cookies.jwt
    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, "Company_Special_Code", async (err, decodedToken) => {
            if (err) {
                res.locals.user = null // Set it to null if the user does not exist
// Token is invalid, then telll user that he is don't have access to the resource
                res.status(403).send('Unauthorized')
            } else {
                let user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id)
                res.locals.user = user
                next();
            }
        })
    } else {
// Token does not exists, then telll user that he is don't have access to the resource
      res.status(403).send('Unauthorized')
    }
} else {
  next()
}
}

module.exports = {
    checkUser
}
```